# Why are my drives "swapped" in Windows 10 recovery mode?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I had booted into recovery mode recently to delete a file that was on my `C:\` Drive. However, when I `cd` from `X:\` to `C:\` , it actually contained contents normally on my `D:\` drive. Navigating to the `D:\` Drive in the recovery console, I saw that it instead had the contents normally in my `C:\` drive were in there. Why is this and is this a cause for concern? Is the naming scheme of drives irrelevant between recovery mode and normal boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because letter assignments are part of the OS configuration, not actually internal to the disk (or the filesystem).

If I remember correctly, old Windows and MS-DOS versions used to assign drive letters on *every* reboot in order based on physical connections (first IDE port, second IDE port, etc). Nowadays Windows no longer does so, and just stores the device mappings in the Registry to make them persistent after the 1st boot.

The recovery mode and the install USB stick both boot a completely separate OS (a read-only WinPE "mini OS" image); it deliberately doesn't use the main system's registry (because maybe the registry being bad is the reason you're in recovery mode), so every time you boot it, you get fresh assignments.

This generally should not cause problems; Windows recovery tools which deal with such paths (such as `bcdedit`) actually deal with GUID-based paths under the hood and only convert to "normal" paths when displaying them on screen.

Answer (score 1):

The drive from which Windows boots was always called `C:\`,
then the other drives were allocated letters from `D` and so on.

In later years, Microsoft has decided that the recovery boot media
shall do it differently :
The recovery boot disk is now called `X`, which has liberated the letter `C`.
So from now on the recovery disk is called `X`,
and the first internal disk is called `C`, and so on.

In your case, your normal Windows boot disk is apparently Disk 1,
so under normal boot from this disk it would be called `C`,
and your other disk, which is Disk 0, is called `D`.

But when booting from
the recovery disk, it names the disks by physical order of connection
to the motherboard, so it calls your Disk 0 by the name of `C`
(which is normally `D`) and your Disk 1 is called `D`
(which is normally `C`).

This is not an inversion - it's just the normal way that Windows
names the disks that it finds on the computer.
As long as you understand this principle and use the disks correctly,
then everything is OK.

Comment: @DanielB: I don't read the question this way: "Navigating to the D:\ Drive in the recovery console, I saw that it instead had the contents normally in my C:\ drive were in there". This is exactly what I address in my answer. Whatever is the boot drive, it will always be C.

Comment: @DanielB: The description is indeed a bit muddled, but the recovery disk will never be on anything else than C and the first internal disk will be on D. Those drive-letter allocations may be surprising for first-time users.

Comment: @DanielB: I believe you now (I tried). It's been years since I booted a recovery disk and Microsoft has changed things without notice (as usual). I modified my answer to explain what I suppose is happening to the poster.